# How can i get sub string that is after three #?

Tags: android, substring

I have a string "Century Gothic#12,75#True#FFFFFFFF" and i would be able to retrive just the string "FFFFFFFF" so how can i use substring to get the string after the third #? or can i just start in someway to substring the String from the end?

Comment: `String str = "Century Gothic#12,75#True#FFFFFFFF";
         
         String finalc = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('#'), str.length());`

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes great that's what i was looking for ty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "Century Gothic#12,75#True#FFFFFFFF";
String[] parts = s.split("#");
//parts[2] = "FFFFFFFF"
```